# get raw video data from ExoPlayer on java mobile app

Tags: java, exoplayer

i am trying to stream my RTSP camera to my mobile app which is written in Java, I used exoPlayer to view the video and it is working fine, here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.OptIn;
import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem;
import androidx.media3.common.Player;
import androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspMediaSource;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.MediaSource;

public class VideoStreamer {
    private ExoPlayer player;
    private final Context context;

    public VideoStreamer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        initializePlayer();
    }

    @OptIn(markerClass = UnstableApi.class)
    private void initializePlayer() {
        Log.d("", "initializePlayer: ");
        player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();

        Uri rtspUri = Uri.parse("my_rtsp_link");
        MediaSource mediaSource = new RtspMediaSource.Factory().createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(rtspUri));

        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
        player.prepare();
    }

    public ExoPlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }
}
```

now my problem is I don't know how to get the data frames or raw data from the camera I am streaming on,

I looked for some solutions such as using MediaCodec, but I didn't know how to do so, my plan is to send these data to an API